# Pinterest custom share button works but only if user already logged in on Pinterest

Tags: share, customization, pinterest

I am using the following code to generate a custom pinterest share functionality on the images on my website:

```
<a class="btn-pinterest" href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/bookmarklet/?media=http://www.mywebsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/my-image.png&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.mywebsite.com%2F%23some-title&amp;is_video=false&amp;description=Some+text | Some text" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-pinterest-p"></i></a>
```

This works as expected, BUT only if the user is already logged in at his Pinterest account. If not, login credentials are asked (which is ok), and after successful login the share window with image and description etc. is gone.

So one would have to close the new window with Pinterest account and click the share button again. Which is for obvious reasons very uncool.

With the other social accounts (Facebook, Google+ etc.) this does not happen. After the login as expected you finalize the share by click.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Comment: Sadly no. Problem still exists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this issue is solved by now. At least in my case it seems to work now as expected. Maybe a change inside Pinterest.